# How YQL Cross-Domain works?

Tags: ajax, cross-domain, yql

I was reading [YQL Cross domain ajax request](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-cross-domain-ajax-request-with-yql-and-jquery/), it's very nice, but I don't know how it works, I mean, does yahoo using proxy or another protocol to get contents of website?

Anyone know how it works?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though both domains will be "located" on yahooapis.com

Comment: do you have a scheme of processes, to explain yql? I don't understand why web-robots ignored by yql, even google too.